# Vim: Jump to last non-whitespace character of a file

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I have an ora file that is 200,000 lines long but the last 60,000 some lines are all blank carriage returns/whitespace.

I know <kbd>G</kbd> jumps to the end of a file, but I do I configure vim to jump to the last line or character that is non-whitespace and non-carriage return?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>?</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Go to end of document, search backwards, find a non-whitespace, go. If you need a mapping for that,

```
nnoremap <Leader>G G?\S<CR>:noh<CR>
```

EDIT: This will not work if the last line is not blank. Here's a modification that will work if the last *character* is not blank:

```
nnoremap <Leader>G G$?\S<CR>:noh<CR>
```

To fix *that*, it gets a bit complicated. We'll go to the last character of the file, and test whether it's a whitespace or not. If it is not a whitespace, we're done; but if it is, we can use the previous solution. (This also saves the state of things we mess up, so it will interfere minimally with your work.)

```
function! LastChar()
  let oldsearch = @/
  let oldhls = &hls
  let oldz = @z

  norm G$"zyl
  if match(@z, '\S')
    exe "norm ?\\S\<CR>"
  endif

  let @/ = oldsearch
  let &hls = oldhls
  let @z = oldz
endfunction

nnoremap <Leader>G :call LastChar()<CR>
```

Comment: What if the last line is not blank, but have spaces on its end?

Comment: Consider a file with 3 lines of code: `aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc`. The `ccc` line have trailing spaces on its end. You want to move to the last `c`, but it willn't work.

Comment: Initially, the cursor is on first `a`. I press `G`, the cursor moves to the first `c`. I type `?\S` and press Enter, the cursor moves to the last `b`. This behavior is OK. What I talked for is that it would be great to have a single solution which will work for both cases. That is, for the case described in the original post and for the case that I described here in comments. EDIT: Oh, I see the edit in your last comment :D

Comment: Ah okay I finally see what you meant. Sorry about being thick :P Unfortunately, I can't come up with something simple if the last character is a space.

Comment: Well, in a such a case we can use `Gg_`.

Comment: @johnc.j. The last edit might address your concerns :)

Comment: Works perfect, thank you. I have already upvoted, would upvote twice if I could :D

Answer (score 3):

`(count)g_` will go to the last non-blank character of a line `count` lines below the current line. So a silly way you could do it is:

```
999999999g_
```

As a mapping:

```
nnoremap <leader>g_ 999999999g_
```

Answer (score 0):

I use

```txt
nnoremap G G{}
```

It jumps to the line after the last paragraph.